# Integral $\int\frac{e^x \sin x}{\sinh x+\cosh x}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int\frac{e^x \sin x}{\sinh x+\cosh x}dx$$

I know that the answer simplifies to $-\cos x$, but I have no idea how to start this question.
Would I use integration by parts? u-substitution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that by their definition,
$$\sinh x + \cosh x=e^x$$

Comment: Or, if not from their definition, it is simply proved.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: First multiply nominator and denominator with:
$$
\cosh{x}-\sinh{x}
$$
to make the denominator equal to 1 since $(\cosh{x})^2-(\sinh{x})^2=1$.

Otherwise use directly that $\cosh{x}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\sinh{x}=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ hence the denominator equals $e^x$ which is canceled with the $e^x$ in the nominator. So the integrand is just $\sin{x}$.

Comment: That's a good hint and at all, but I have a hunch that the questioner is not at all familiar hyperbolic trig identities.

Answer (score 2):

Write sinh, cosh in terms of $e^x, e^{-x}$. Then cancel terms from teh numerator and denominator.